# R: Preprocessing text strings with gsub takes way too long

Tags: r, preprocessor, text-mining, gsub

I appreciate your help very much for my problem. I've been on this for weeks now, and couldn't find a solution..Sorry for the long description. I figured I post many details, so you get the problem entirely, although it's not hard to grasp.

**Situation:**

Data frame consisting of 4 million entries (total size: 250 MB). Two columns: `ID` and `TEXT`. Text strings are each up to 200 characters.

**Task:**

Preprocessing the text strings

**Problem:**

It takes too long. On my 8GB RAM Dual-Core machine: Cancelled after 1 day. On a 70GB 8-Core Amazon EC2 instance: Cancelled after 1 day.

**Details:**

I am basically

- Counting how often certain words appear in one string
- Write this number into a new column (COUNT)
- Replace this (counted) word
- Replace other words (which I don't need to count before)
- Replace some regular expressions

The vectors which are used as patterns look like this:

```
"\\bWORD1\\b|\\bWORD2\\b|\\bWORD3\\b|\\bWORD4\\b..."
```

Thus, those 'replacement vectors' are character vectors of length 1, each containing up to 800 words

**Main:**

```
library("parallel")
library("stringr")

preprocessText<-function(x){

  # Replace the 'html-and'
  arguments<-list(pattern="\\&amp\\;",replacement="and",x=x, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  # Remove some special characters
   arguments<-list(pattern="[^-[:alnum:]\\'\\:\\/\\$\\%\\.\\,\\+\\-\\#\\@\\_\\!\\?+[:space:]]",replacement="",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  # Lowercase 
  arguments<-list(string=y,pattern=tolower(rep_ticker))
  first<-do.call(str_match,arguments)  

  # Identify signal words and count them
  # Need to be done in parts, because otherwise R can't handle this many at once
  arguments<-list(string=x, pattern=rep_words_part1)
  t1<-do.call(str_extract_all,arguments)

  arguments<-list(string=x, pattern=rep_words_part2)
  t2<-do.call(str_extract_all,arguments)

  arguments<-list(string=x, pattern=rep_words_part3)
  t3<-do.call(str_extract_all,arguments)

  arguments<-list(string=x, pattern=rep_words_part4)
  t4<-do.call(str_extract_all,arguments)

  count=length(t1[[1]])+length(t2[[1]])+length(t3[[1]])+length(t4[[1]])
  signal_words=c(t1[[1]],t2[[1]],t3[[1]],t4[[1]])


  # Replacements

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_wordsA,replacement=" [wordA] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments) 

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_wordB_part1,replacement=" [wordB] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_wordB_part2,replacement=" [wordB] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_wordB_part3,replacement=" [wordB] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_wordB_part4,replacement=" [wordB] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_email,replacement=" [email_adress] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_url,replacement=" [url] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_wordC,replacement=" [wordC] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  # Some regular expressions
  arguments<-list(pattern="\\+[[:digit:]]*.?[[:digit:]]+%",replacement=" [positive_percentage] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern="-[[:digit:]]*.?[[:digit:]]+%",replacement=" [negative_percentage] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern="[[:digit:]]*.?[[:digit:]]+%",replacement=" [percentage] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern="\\$[[:digit:]]*.?[[:digit:]]+",replacement=" [dollar_value] ",x=y,ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern="\\+[[:digit:]]*.?[[:digit:]]+",replacement=" [pos_number] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)# remaining numbers 
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern="\\-[[:digit:]]*.?[[:digit:]]+",replacement=" [neg_number] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern="[[:digit:]]*.?[[:digit:]]+",replacement=" [number] ",x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)   

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_question,replacement=" [question] ", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)    


  # Unify synonyms
  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_syno1,replacement="happy", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_syno2,replacement="sad", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_syno3,replacement="people", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_syno4,replacement="father", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_syno5,replacement="mother", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  arguments<-list(pattern=rep_syno6,replacement="money", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE)
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  # Remove words
  # Punctuation (I know there a pre-defined R commands for this, but I need to customize this
  arguments<-list(pattern=rem_punct,replacement="", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE) 
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments)  

  arguments<-list(pattern=rem_linebreak,replacement=" ", x=y, ignore.case=TRUE) #Remove line breaks
  y<-do.call(gsub, arguments) 

  #Append Positive or Negative Emotion  
  arguments<-list(x=y)
  y<-do.call(appendEmotion, arguments)  


  # Output
  result<-list(
    textclean=y,
    first_signal=first,
    all_signals=signal_words,
    signal_count=count)

  return(result)
}

resultList<-mclapply(dataframe$text_column,preprocessText)
```

(The return would be a list, which I plan to convert to a data.frame).

Before, I also tried to call each `gsub` seperately, thus performing the first `gsub` on every text string, then the second `gsub` and so on.. but I guess that this was even less efficient.

The code itself works, but for me it seems that this can be speeded up. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with hash tables, which is what I heard could be a solution.

Appreciate your advice and help very much!

*Definition of the one function called inside `preprocessText`*

```
appendEmotion<-function(x){

  if (grepl(app_pos,x)){
    x<-paste(x," [posemo] ")
  } 
  if(grepl(app_neg,x)){
    x<-paste(x," [negemo] ")
  }  
  #Output
  return(x)
}
```

Example Data:

```
+------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  ID  |                     Text                      |
+------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 123  | My dad and me finished the race top 5%        |
| 456  | Look at this http://www.google.com, Like it ? |
  ..
+------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Should become

```
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  ID  |                     Text                              |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| 123  | my father and me finished the race top [percentage]   |
| 456  | look at this [url] like it [question]                 |
  ..
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Profiling your function would be a lot easier if you provided some example data. Also, `do.call` is unnecessary here.

Comment: In addition to what @JoshuaUlrich said, I would also suggest using `fixed=TRUE` argument where ever you are not using regex pattern.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich @geektrader: is this example data sufficient? The vectors for the `pattern` part of `gsub` all look like the one example provided at the beginning

Comment: This sure looks like a recent post to the r-help mailing list  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/speed-issue-gsub-on-large-data-frame-td4679747.html#a4679769

Comment: yes it is! Also posted it on the mailing list .I figured it is easier to read here.

Comment: I'd do as the Carl Witthoft (on R Help) said, lex the text into words and then perform a series of lookups on these words.  should be much faster than regular expressions example you gave above.  I'd use something other than R as well, it's not really designed for churning through lots of text—Python would be my recommendation.

Comment: Yes, I ended up splitting the text strings into vectors and `fmatch`ing them against a table. Much faster but still, @SamMason, I believe you're right, text processing is not one of R's strengths.